# Cannot choose certificate from smart card

Tags: windows, google-chrome, certificate, smartcard

I have a smart card that I use to login to and sign documents on governmental websites. The card comes with 2 certificates: one for signing into the websites and another for signing documents on the websites. Each certificate has its own PIN.

When I first start Windows and sign into the governmental website through my web browser, Windows asks which certificate to use, but once I choose that certificate the first time, the system does not let me change to use the other certificate unless I restart the system. Windows seems to make the first certificate I choose the default until I reboot. This is a problem as I need to be able to log into a website with the login certificate and then sign documents once logged in with the other certificate.

I am running Windows 10 Home and Google Chrome. I found this registry value while Googling, but it seems to only exist on the Enterprise version of Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-admx-smartcard#admx-smartcard-forcereadingallcertificates

Comment: Do you have the Gemalto software installed locally? Does that intercept the certificate?

Comment: Have you asked your local IT Administrator for assistance.  You absolutely should be able to choose which certificate you want to use.  Are you using any software that is managing the certificate installed?  Windows 10 has built-in support for smart cards. However, the interface is very basic, and it’s easy to kiss the option to select a different certificate

Comment: @Ramhound I am using software made by the governmental entity. The smart card and certificates work as expected on other Windows machines. That's why I suspect there is something wrong with my system in particular.

Comment: @spikey_richie Software provided by the governmental entity is installed locally.

Comment: You will have to provide more information.   Be you sanitize any screenshots